# Setting git private repository project on jenkins server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, ssh, jenkins

I am trying to set git private repo on jenkins server. I have installed git plugin and also github. when I set repo url in jenkins project ui the error is

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true 
ls-remote -h git@github.com:repo/project.git HEAD" returned 
status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedl
```

What I have done up to now:

1. My server user and jenkin user( both are in same server) are different. Though it seems to me these are not related. jenkins user are given all credintial.
2. In my server under var/lib/jenkins/.ssh(.ssh is created by me) I added ssh key . Public key is added to github repo.
3. By swithcting user to jenkins  i can clone the project by this ssh. So i think there is not any public key adding problem.

I have googled the problem. there are many solutions. I tried most of them. But still no solution. Probably I am missing something.

My repo url is something  like this
    git@github.com:repo/project.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `HOME` set in `/var/lib/jenkins/` then i hope all the step you have been done successfully :)

Then one thing may be happen for your case. Like when you switch the user by using:

```
su jenkins
```

This command means that you switch the user but the home directory will be same as a root's home!

So you need to switch user by confirming the specific user home also switched. TO doing so, you need to follow:

```
su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Then you need to generate either the ssh public key once again or just update the known host. This will work.

[Related Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `HOME` is set to when Jenkins is running: git will look for the ssh (public and private) keys under $H`OME/.ssh`.

Simply add a build step with an echo `$HOME`, and make sure your `.ssh` is in that folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i have checked  my jenkins user home directory. There are no ssh key. I created this ssh key under /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh

So i should create it under home/jenkins/.ssh directory? FYI, i saw there are no directory like   jenkins/.ssh for the jenkins user home.

Comment: @Sazzad first: is `$HOME` set to  `/var/lib/jenkins/` when Jenkins is running?

Comment: @Sazzad please run a simple job with one build step including an `echo $HOME`. As long as you don't know where `HOME` is, there is no point in guessing.

Comment: I am not sure how i can able to run the command! did you mean by going server or from jenkins Web UI?

Comment: @Sazzad You absolutely *can* run that command. Create a job in your Jenkins, following the "free form" model , and add a simple build step "`Execute shell`", in which you type "`echo $HOME`". Then execute that job. Simple.

Comment: echo $HOME  returns this /var/lib/jenkins

So what will be the next step? can you suggest  me any reference?

Comment: I can show you full console outputStarted by user jenkins
    Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test terminal/workspace
    [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2657983803941902767.sh
    + echo /var/lib/jenkins
    /var/lib/jenkins
    Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70120/discussion-between-sazzad-and-vonc).